# Overloading + operator in Arduino's String class

Tags: c++, arduino, operator-overloading

In the Arduino `String` [class](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.h), the `+` operator is overloaded many times. I'm porting this code to a Silicon Labs EFM32 part (using ARM GNU) and getting problems. With reference to the header in the link, these are the lines that are giving me grief:

```
friend StringSumHelper &operator+(const StringSumHelper &lhs, const String &rhs);
friend StringSumHelper &operator+(const StringSumHelper &lhs, const char *cstr);
friend StringSumHelper &operator+(const StringSumHelper &lhs, char c);
friend StringSumHelper &operator+(const StringSumHelper &lhs, unsigned char num);

friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, short num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, unsigned short num);

friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, int num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, unsigned int num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, long long num);
friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, unsigned long long num);
```

When compiling, I get the following two error types:

```
C:\arduino_string.h:176:83: error: declaration of C function 'StringSumHelper& operator+(const StringSumHelper&, long long int)' conflicts with
 friend StringSumHelper & operator + (const StringSumHelper &lhs, long long num);

C:\arduino_string.h:155:29: error: previous declaration 'StringSumHelper& operator+(const StringSumHelper&, char)' here
 friend StringSumHelper &operator+(const StringSumHelper &lhs, char c);
                         ^
```

I get a pair of these errors for each overload.

I have commented out the entirety of the corresponding C++ file. I have also removed `#include <avr/pgmspace.h>` from the header, because I'm not using this architecture.

I don't use `friend` methods much, and as the first comment says, they don't have a `this` pointer, so having two parameters for an `overload+` as a member function now makes sense. But it seems to me like this actually may not be the case during compilation? In any case, I don't know what the problem is!

Comment: So where is `here`? The compiler claims there are several declarations. Is there? Can you show a few more lines of the messages? Also, the operator being a `friend` means that it not a member function, so it has no `this` pointer.

Comment: Ah, there is one error that says "declaration of C function 'StingSumHelper & operator+(..)' conflicts with...". Could it be that these functions are being compiled in C for some reason?

Comment: @EdKing Please, provide minimal code that reproduces it (problematic part of `String` class declarations and definitions) and compiler error messages. It is difficult to understand what happens now.

Comment: See above for an edit - there's only so much extra I can post!

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the 1.6.8 SAM files. Are you sure you didn't take the AVR files by accident?

Comment: I downloaded the latest Arduino installation yesterday (1.6.10). This code is taken from the `WString.h` file in the core. I'm pretty sure these are AVR files anyway, but should that make a difference to the compilation of the C++?

Comment: Considering that AVR and SAM use completely different compilers (although both still GCC), I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: But I have ported this code before (to a Renesas RX63N using KPIT GNU a couple of years ago), without issue, so what is the issue with it this time? Is there something I'm missing in ARM GNU? Is there anything wrong with the code, C++ wise?